# Fluent NHibernate - Dialect does not support DbType.Xml (SQLite)

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a custom NHibernate XMLtype (Converts POCO to XML on the fly) so i can save objects in the DB.

This works with SQL Server 2014 without any issues. However, when trying to run our unit tests which use SQLite, I'm getting loads of errors due to this.

System.ArgumentException: Dialect does not support DbType.Xml
Parameter name: typecode.

I'm using a custom type similar to what was mentioned here: [How to map XML type column to a strongly typed object property with NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009117/how-to-map-xml-type-column-to-a-strongly-typed-object-property-with-nhibernate)

Now I need to figure out how to get this type working with SQLite.

What I have done:

-When registering the SQLiteConfiguration i specify a custom Dialect that registers the XMl ColumnType:

```
   Configuration config = null;
            var db = SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(_connectionString).ShowSql().Dialect("InvestX.Data.nHibernate.DbContext.SQLiteDialectWithManifestTyping");


 _sessionFactory = new DbSessionFactory(Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(db)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
            .ExposeConfiguration(c => config = c)
            .BuildSessionFactory());
```

...

```
base.RegisterColumnType(System.Data.DbType.Xml, "Xml");
```

-Ensure that the XmlType returns th eproper SQLType

It works great on SQL Server 2012, but fails miserably on SQLite.

**Other Thoughts**
I have had success with manually adding the column as an XML Type to my database through an ALTER SCRIPT, and then changing my NHibernate Binding to bind as a nvarchar(MAX).  This works in all scenarios except when my system needs to create a new Database from scratch. It's a temporary solution (ie, most permanent solution) so i'm not a huge fan of it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It may be worth writing your own SQL dialect for what you need to do: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348642/how-to-write-custom-nhibernate-dialect ,

Comment: Just as a side comment - from experience I wouldn't recommend running unit tests against SQLite if your mappings were made for Sql Server. I know people out there promise you can, but you will constantly be running into these type of headaches.

Comment: @cbp You're 100% correct. Though I've gotten around this, I can fully see how a very complex DB would run into issues with this.